# Servicio web que consuma una DLL C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

quiero saber como seria la manera en que un web service pueda consumir una DLL (un proyecto de biblioteca de clases) para poder utilizar mi proyecto de biblioteca de clases, cualquier ayuda se los agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el primer paso seria agregar al referencia a esa libreria, ya sea que tengas solo la dll o so es un proyecto dentro de la misma solucion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces seleccionas si es una libreria del framework o la buscas en la carpeta si es que es una de terceros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que la tengas referenciada solo tienes que instanciar la clase que esta defina como public

Comment: solo con instanciar la clase en el web service, con eso es suficiente para hacer las actividades correspondientes que se tienen en la clase public?

Comment: imagino sabias que debias definir el `using` del namespace donde esta la `class` de la libreria, pero mas alla de eso si con solo instanciar alcanza

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias, lo haré de esa forma :)